# Enumitem: no margin for roman labels

Tags: margins, enumerate, roman-numerals

I would simply like a roman style labeling with no index but `leftmargin=*` doesn't work when combined with the label option. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}    
\section*{First section - ok}   
        \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
            \item 1 is alligned with the letter 'F' in 'First section'
            \item 2 is alligned with the letter 'F' in 'First section'
        \end{enumerate}
    \section*{Second section - not ok}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries(\roman*),leftmargin=*]
            \item (i) is NOT alligned with the letter 'S' in 'Second section'
            \item (ii) is NOT alligned with the letter 'S' in 'Second section'
        \end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, list labels are right-aligned.  You won't notice it in arabic numerals until you exceed `9`, but it is immediately apparent in roman numerals.

So I think, you are looking for `align=left`.  Not only will that align the left side of labels with each other, but will set them to the left side of the space allocate for the label width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}    
\section*{First section - ok}   
        \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
            \item 1 is aligned with the letter 'F' in 'First section'
            \item 2 is aligned with the letter 'F' in 'First section'
        \end{enumerate}
    \section*{Second section - now ok}
        \begin{enumerate}[align=left,label=\bfseries(\roman*),leftmargin=*]
            \item (i) is NOW aligned with the letter 'S' in 'Second section'
            \item (ii) is NOW aligned with the letter 'S' in 'Second section'
        \end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll upvote if you delete both instances of NOT and replace all four intances of "alligned" with "aligned". :-) You may also want to point out that, with roman numerals, `\labelwidth` is calculated so as to accommodate 8 items in the list, as `(viii)` is the widest roman numeral less than 12.

Comment: @Mico LOL.  Thanks.

Comment: Congrats on passing the 200k rep mark!!!

Comment: @Mico Hey!  Thank you again!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I accepted your answer but I have a question: if align=left does both jobs why do we need to keep leftmargin=* ?

Comment: @cgss Actually, you don't need it in the `align=left` case...but it does change the indent a little.